# Python urllib2 not found

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm getting an error when testing a python script which is installed on my Android Emulator running SDK 2.2

I have installed "Python_for_android_r1.apk" and "sl4a_r5.apk" in my emulator. It seems that my code is trying to import the following:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen
```

And from what I can tell urllib2 is not found based on the error below.

```
( FILE "/home/manuel/A;tanaStudio3Workspace/python-for-android/python-build/output/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py, line 124 in urlopen )
```

Any ideas how I can fix this problem??

Answer (score 1):

Your urllib module seems to be found.  If the module is not found, python will return you an error at the import.

Looking at the error, it appears that you are having problems with urlopen.  Is the url you are trying to open valid?  Line 124 in urllib2 refers to the opener that you are using to get your response.

Answer (score 0):

`A;tanaStudio3Workspace`

this is weird. You have no problem with your import module but the path look really wrong. I could assume if you fix the path, it will be alright but for further investigation you need to provide a real traceback.